# What is the optimal time for exercising American call and put option?

Tags: options, option-pricing, derivatives, american-options

A `9 month` American option (underlying) is known to pay dividend of `USD 1 and USD 0.75` at the end of the `3rd and the 07th` month respectively. The `strike price` considered is `USD 45`. The `Risk Free Rate` is continuously compounded and is fixed at `6%` over the tenure. The `stock` is currently trading at `42`. The `put` options are trading at `USD 7.5` and the `call` options at `USD 4.0`. What would be the optimum time to exercise the call and put option based on the information given above?

The answers for the above questions are :-

a) The American call option should be bought and exercised at the second dividend.

b) The American Put option should be bought, but should not be exercised before the first dividend payoff.

How to arrive at this solution?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Couldn't get a head start with respect to which direction to proceed. Could you please share some lead in order to attain the solution?